# Firestore Query Nested Map

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Looking to construct a query against a firestore collection ('parent') where the documents have a nested map (2 logical levels deep).  Specifically when the first map has dynamic keys which are not known at the time of running the query.  As an example:

Document 1

```
{
  codes: {
     abc: {
        id: 'hi'
     },
     def: {
        id: 'there'
     }
  }
}
```

Document 2

```
{
  codes: {
     ghi: {
        id: 'you'
     },
     zmp: {
        id: 'guys'
     }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a WHERE clause that takes a wildcard for a key in the document.  ie.

```
firestore.collection('parent').WHERE('codes.*.id', '==', 'there')
  // Results in Document 1
```

or

```
firestore.collection('parent').WHERE('codes.*.id', '==', 'you')
  // Results in Document 2
```

Is there any way to achieve this behavior without having to resort to generating subcollection documents to be used for indexing, or polluting the document itself with a second map that maps ids to codes.

**== Not ideal solution 1 (subcollections) ==**

Build out the server so that when these documents are filed, a subcollection ('child') is maintained with documents that contain the related information.  As an example filing Document 1 above would require filing two documents in the child subcollection:

```
{
  id: 'hi'
  code: 'abc'
}

{
  id: 'there'
  code: 'def'
}
```

Now we can query for the id we want, and get the parent reference, and follow that all the way back to the parent...

```
firestore.collectionGroup('child').where('id', '==', 'there')
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    for(const doc of snapshot.docs) {
      return doc.ref.parent.parent
    }
    return Promise.reject('no parents, how sad.')
  })
  .then(ref => ref.get())
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.data())
  .then(parent => {
     // Thank goodness, the parent is Document 1!
  }
```

The downside to this is maintenance of the sub collections, as well as a number of extra operations against firestore.

**== Not ideal solution 2 (model pollution) ==**

Another way to achieve this is to implement another map or an array in the document itself which simply contains the ids which would then let us query on those values.  ie

```
{
  codes: {
     abc: {
        id: 'hi'
     },
     def: {
        id: 'there'
     }
  },
  codeids:['hi','there']
}
```

Although this is easy to query:

```
.WHERE('codeids', 'ARRAY CONTAINS', 'hi')
```

I don't like the idea of adding fields that are not meaningful to the consumer of the document (the purpose of the field only being to facilitate a documents ability to be queried due to system constraints)

Open to suggestions!